# How to make windbg open executable command open an app as administrator

Tags: windows, windbg

I want to debug an console app with windbg, using the `open executable` command, I can attach the console app, but the console app was not started as administrator.

I know I can start an elevated command line by right click the `cmd.exe` then choose `run as administrator` then run the console app, since the console app will not stop in its execution, it will end immediately, causing no chance for me to `attach` to windbg.

Of course I can pause the console app in the middle of its processing, giving a chance to attach to windbg, say read lines from keyboard, but I am wondering if there ways to directly using windbg `open executable' command to attach an app under administrator privilege?

Comment: [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh406274(v=vs.85).aspx), if WinDbg is run as administrator, any process it spawns should have the same permissions. Quoting: *"because the target application is a child process of the debugger, it inherits the debugger's permissions."*

Comment: But in my case the child process wants to create a job, invoking `CreateJobObject`, failed with `access denied`.

Comment: Then I think you have to fall back to your workaround solution of pausing your debug target to give you time to attach the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a String value regkey under 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers

ex. C:\windbg.exe = RUNASADMIN (REG_SZ)

Refer here to get more details-
http://www.verboon.info/2011/03/running-an-application-as-administrator-or-in-compatibility-mode/